# rlang, fpp3 R package: Error: `vars` must be a character vector upon calling aggregate_key()

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

I'm working through the Hyndman fpp3 package based on this markdown document.  https://github.com/robjhyndman/ISI_Workshop_2019/blob/master/5_reconciliation/reconciliation.Rmd

I just couldn't find out why the following code fail to run

```
PBS %>%
  aggregate_key(ATC1/ATC2, Scripts = sum(Scripts)) %>%
  filter(Month == yearmonth("1991 Jul")) %>% print(n=18)
```

I keep receiving the following error each time I run the above.

```
New names:
* `` -> ...1
* `` -> ...2
* `` -> ...3
* `` -> ...4
* `` -> ...5
* ...
Error: `vars` must be a character vector
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
`vars` must be a character vector
Backtrace:
  8. fabletools::aggregate_key(., ATC1/ATC2, Scripts = sum(Scripts))
  2. tsibble::build_tsibble_meta(...)
 10. dplyr::mutate(...)
 20. tsibble:::retain_tsibble(mut_data, key(.data), index(.data))
 21. tsibble:::duplicated_key_index(data, key, index)
 22. dplyr::grouped_df(as_tibble(data), key)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

> rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
`vars` must be a character vector
Backtrace:
     █
  1. └─`%>%`(...)
  2.   ├─base::withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
  3.   └─base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
  4.     └─base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
  5.       └─`_fseq`(`_lhs`)
  6.         └─magrittr::freduce(value, `_function_list`)
  7.           └─function_list[[i]](value)
  8.             ├─fabletools::aggregate_key(., ATC1/ATC2, Scripts = sum(Scripts))
  9.             └─fabletools:::aggregate_key.tbl_ts(., ATC1/ATC2, Scripts = sum(Scripts))
 10.               └─`%>%`(...)
 11.                 ├─base::withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
 12.                 └─base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
 13.                   └─base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
 14.                     └─fabletools:::`_fseq`(`_lhs`)
 15.                       └─magrittr::freduce(value, `_function_list`)
 16.                         ├─base::withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
 17.                         └─function_list[[k]](value)
 18.                           ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
 19.                           └─tsibble:::mutate.tbl_ts(...)
 20.                             └─tsibble:::retain_tsibble(mut_data, key(.data), index(.data))
 21.                               └─tsibble:::duplicated_key_index(data, key, index)
 22.                                 └─dplyr::grouped_df(as_tibble(data), key)
```

I suspect this is due to some package dependencies.

the fpp3 library give me the following packages versin

```
> library(fpp3)
── Attaching packages ──────────────────────────────── fpp3 0.2 ──
✓ tibble      3.0.0           ✓ tsibble     0.8.6      
✓ dplyr       0.8.99.9002     ✓ tsibbledata 0.1.0      
✓ tidyr       1.0.2           ✓ feasts      0.1.3      
✓ lubridate   1.7.8           ✓ fable       0.1.2.9000 
✓ ggplot2     3.3.0           
── Conflicts ─────────────────────────────────── fpp3_conflicts ──
x lubridate::date()   masks base::date()
x dplyr::filter()     masks stats::filter()
x tsibble::id()       masks dplyr::id()
x tsibble::interval() masks lubridate::interval()
x dplyr::lag()        masks stats::lag()
```

session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] fable_0.1.2.9000  feasts_0.1.3      fabletools_0.1.3 
 [4] tsibbledata_0.1.0 tsibble_0.8.6     ggplot2_3.3.0    
 [7] lubridate_1.7.8   tidyr_1.0.2       dplyr_0.8.99.9002
[10] tibble_3.0.0      fpp3_0.2         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6      rstudioapi_0.11   magrittr_1.5     
 [4] tidyselect_1.0.0  munsell_0.5.0     anytime_0.3.7    
 [7] colorspace_1.4-1  R6_2.4.1          rlang_0.4.5.9000 
[10] fansi_0.4.1       tools_3.6.0       grid_3.6.0       
[13] gtable_0.3.0      cli_2.0.2         withr_2.1.2      
[16] ellipsis_0.3.0    assertthat_0.2.1  lifecycle_0.2.0  
[19] crayon_1.3.4      purrr_0.3.3       vctrs_0.2.99.9011
[22] glue_1.4.0        compiler_3.6.0    pillar_1.4.3     
[25] generics_0.0.2    scales_1.1.0      pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: Can you please share a small slice of `PBS` that we can use to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @ArtemSokolov updated with answer reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by regressing back to CRAN version of some packages
[rlang, fpp3 R package: Error: `vars` must be a character vector upon calling aggregate_key()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61229355/rlang-fpp3-r-package-error-vars-must-be-a-character-vector-upon-calling-agg)

I notice the question was duplicated on stackoverflow after being migrated from stats.stackexchange

Could any admin help how we can reconcile these duplicates?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing similar solution. Is downgrading the only path? Sound like a bug.

Comment: @user1700890, I ended up not using it because it doesn't seem to be stable anyways. Otherwise, yes, last time I have to ensure to only use CRAN  versions of the packages. Since then, R 4.0.0 has been released, so not sure what's the current status.