# R fpp3 package: Error:`vars` must be a character vector when calling accuracy() method

Tags: r

I am learning fpp3 and trying one of examples

```
recent_production <- aus_production %>% filter(year(Quarter) >= 1992)
fit_beer <- recent_production %>%
model(TSLM(Beer ~ trend() + season()))
fc_beer <- forecast(fit_beer)
fc_beer %>%
  autoplot(recent_production) +
  ggtitle("Forecasts of beer production using regression") +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("megalitres") 
fc_beer %>%
  accuracy(recent_production)
```

And the erros is

```
Erros: `vars` must be a character vector.
```

When running `rlang::last_error()`

```
<error/rlang_error>
`vars` must be a character vector.
Backtrace:
9. fabletools::accuracy(., recent_production)
12. tsibble:::transmute.tbl_ts(...)
17. tsibble:::mutate.tbl_ts(.data, !!!lst_quos)
18. tsibble:::retain_tsibble(mut_data, key(.data), index(.data))
19. tsibble:::duplicated_key_index(data, key, index)
20. dplyr::grouped_df(as_tibble(data), key)
```

AND

```
<error/rlang_error>
`vars` must be a character vector.
Backtrace:
     █
  1. └─fc_beer %>% accuracy(recent_production)
  2.   ├─base::withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
  3.   └─base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
  4.     └─base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
  5.       └─`_fseq`(`_lhs`)
  6.         └─magrittr::freduce(value, `_function_list`)
  7.           ├─base::withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
  8.           └─function_list[[k]](value)
  9.             ├─fabletools::accuracy(., recent_production)
 10.             └─fabletools:::accuracy.fbl_ts(., recent_production)
 11.               ├─dplyr::transmute(object, .fc = !!resp, .dist = !!dist, !!!syms(by))
 12.               └─tsibble:::transmute.tbl_ts(...)
 13.                 ├─dplyr::mutate(.data, !!!lst_quos)
 14.                 ├─fabletools:::mutate.fbl_ts(.data, !!!lst_quos)
 15.                 │ └─fabletools::as_fable(...)
 16.                 ├─base::NextMethod()
 17.                 └─tsibble:::mutate.tbl_ts(.data, !!!lst_quos)
 18.                   └─tsibble:::retain_tsibble(mut_data, key(.data), index(.data))
 19.                     └─tsibble:::duplicated_key_index(data, key, index)
 20.                       └─dplyr::grouped_df(as_tibble(data), key)
```

Session Info is

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] zh_CN.UTF-8/zh_CN.UTF-8/zh_CN.UTF-8/C/zh_CN.UTF-8/zh_CN.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] fable_0.2.0       feasts_0.1.3      fabletools_0.1.3  tsibbledata_0.1.0 tsibble_0.8.6    
 [6] ggplot2_3.3.1     lubridate_1.7.8   tidyr_1.1.0       dplyr_1.0.0       tibble_3.0.1     
[11] fpp3_0.2         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6     pillar_1.4.4     compiler_3.6.3   tools_3.6.3      digest_0.6.25   
 [6] lifecycle_0.2.0  gtable_0.3.0     anytime_0.3.7    pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_0.4.6     
[11] cli_2.0.2        rstudioapi_0.11  withr_2.2.0      generics_0.0.2   vctrs_0.3.1     
[16] grid_3.6.3       tidyselect_1.1.0 glue_1.4.1       R6_2.4.1         fansi_0.4.1     
[21] farver_2.0.3     purrr_0.3.4      magrittr_1.5     scales_1.1.1     ellipsis_0.3.1  
[26] assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_1.4-1 labeling_0.3     munsell_0.5.0    crayon_1.3.4
```

I have seen questions that same to it see:[rlang, fpp3 R package: Error: `vars` must be a character vector upon calling aggregate_key()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205790/rlang-fpp3-r-package-error-vars-must-be-a-character-vector-upon-calling-agg)

but I still can solve this problem

Comment: The dplyr v1.0.0 release has broken tsibble v0.8.6 and fabletools 0.1.3. These development versions of tsibble and fabletools have fixed these breaking changes, but it is taking some time to get the updated versions onto CRAN.